# How do you design typefaces?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, typefaces

**Hi Everyone**
I am working with a client and he wants me to design handwritten typefaces. I tried it with mouse but it is hard to do with mouse. 
**Any idea of how do you do such task?**

Comment: Hi Tester, welcome to GDSE and thank you for your question. As it stands, though, your question is way to broad for our Q&A format. We might be able to help if you could show us what you've tried and where you're stuck. Read  more in the [Help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. hand draw your characters. I'd set up a sheet with a grid for x-height, cap height, em width etc
2. Refine till your happy with them
3. Scan them
4. In Illustrator, autotrace each character. Then refine.
5. If you want to create a typeface, then work with Fontographer or similar. You can paste each character into Fontographers character grid.
6. Generate your font format. OpenType, Truetype etc

I know this is a simplified run through, but that's the basics of how I'd do it.

Comment: And the refining or other pointer-work **may** be easier with a graphics tablet and stylus rather than a mouse. And lots of enlargement.

Comment: Then you spend an eternity preparing kerning pairs :)

Comment: @AndrewLeach You are right. I wanted to use graphic tablet but I don't have it right now. I would be easy if I would have it. Can you refer to best graphic tablet?

Comment: @Tester StackExchange doesn't do recommendations because they are out of date within weeks if not hours.